# Detect client disconnect when network adapter was turned off

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have trouble with detecting client disconnect from host. Currently my code looks like this:

```
Task.Run(() => {
 // Create server
 Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) {
  ReceiveTimeout = -1,
 };

 server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
 server.Listen(-1);

 // Start listening
 while (true) {
  Socket socket = server.Accept();

  new Thread(() => {
   try {
    Process(socket);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    Trace.WriteLine("Socket connection processing error: " + ex.Message);
   }
  }).Start();
 }
});

// Host client process
void Process(Socket socket) {
  byte[] response;
  int received;
  var ip = IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint) socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
  Events.OnNodeConnected(ip);

  while (true) {
   // Rceive data
   response = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
   received = socket.Receive(response);

   // Check connection
   if (!socket.IsConnected()) {
    socket.Close();
    Events.OnNodeDisconnected(ip);
    return;
   }

   try {
    // Decode recieved data
    List < byte > respBytesList = new List < byte > (response);
```

And the *IsConnected()* extension:

```
public static class SocketExtensions {
 public static bool IsConnected(this Socket socket) {
  try {
   return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
  } catch (SocketException) {
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Works when I close the application, but not when I turn off the network card. I'm testing this on Debian virtual machines running on VirtualBox. Is there any way to detect disconnection in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Works when I close the application, but not when I turn off the network card.

Turning off the network card is actually not a disconnect. If the network card is turned on again the existing connection can continue (providing the interface has still the same IP address) - this is not unusual for example when suspending a laptop and resuming it later.

With TCP a real disconnect is only an explicit disconnect (FIN gets send) which is done when explicitly closing the socket or which gets implicitly done by the OS kernel on application exit or when the application crashes.

What you instead ask for is not an explicit disconnect but to detect if the peer is **currently** not reachable, like when the line is (temporarily) disconnected or the system has crashed. This can be done by having some kind of heartbeat either at the application level or at the TCP level. The latter is called TCP keep alive and works by sending empty TCP packets and check if an ACK is sent back. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171344/3081018) for an example on how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I have similary problem, when i want to know if my network interface is known or not

i am using this piece of code to check the different network interfaces:

file NetworkMonitor.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

namespace NetWork.Plus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The NetworkMonitor class monitors network speed for each network adapter on the computer,
    /// using classes for Performance counter in .NET library.
    /// </summary>
    public class NetworkMonitor
    {
        private Timer timer;                        // The timer event executes every second to refresh the values in adapters.
        private ArrayList adapters;                 // The list of adapters on the computer.
        private ArrayList monitoredAdapters;        // The list of currently monitored adapters.

        public NetworkMonitor()
        {
            this.adapters   =   new ArrayList();
            this.monitoredAdapters  =   new ArrayList();
            EnumerateNetworkAdapters();

            timer   =   new Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed   +=  new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerates network adapters installed on the computer.
        /// </summary>
        private void EnumerateNetworkAdapters()
        {
            PerformanceCounterCategory category =   new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");

            foreach (string name in category.GetInstanceNames())
            {
                // This one exists on every computer.
                if (name == "MS TCP Loopback interface")
                    continue;
                // Create an instance of NetworkAdapter class, and create performance counters for it.
                NetworkAdapter adapter  =   new NetworkAdapter(name);
                adapter.dlCounter   =   new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", name);
                adapter.ulCounter   =   new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", name);
                this.adapters.Add(adapter);         // Add it to ArrayList adapter
            }
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (NetworkAdapter adapter in this.monitoredAdapters)
                adapter.refresh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get instances of NetworkAdapter for installed adapters on this computer.
        /// </summary>
        public NetworkAdapter[] Adapters
        {
            get
            {
                return (NetworkAdapter[])this.adapters.ToArray(typeof(NetworkAdapter));
            }
        }

        // Enable the timer and add all adapters to the monitoredAdapters list, unless the adapters list is empty.
        public void StartMonitoring()
        {
            if (this.adapters.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(NetworkAdapter adapter in this.adapters)
                    if (!this.monitoredAdapters.Contains(adapter))
                    {
                        this.monitoredAdapters.Add(adapter);
                        adapter.init();
                    }

                timer.Enabled   =   true;
            }
        }

        // Enable the timer, and add the specified adapter to the monitoredAdapters list
        public void StartMonitoring(NetworkAdapter adapter)
        {
            if (!this.monitoredAdapters.Contains(adapter))
            {
                this.monitoredAdapters.Add(adapter);
                adapter.init();
            }
            timer.Enabled   =   true;
        }

        // Disable the timer, and clear the monitoredAdapters list.
        public void StopMonitoring()
        {
            this.monitoredAdapters.Clear();
            timer.Enabled   =   false;
        }

        // Remove the specified adapter from the monitoredAdapters list, and disable the timer if the monitoredAdapters list is empty.
        public void StopMonitoring(NetworkAdapter adapter)
        {
            if (this.monitoredAdapters.Contains(adapter))
                this.monitoredAdapters.Remove(adapter); 
            if(this.monitoredAdapters.Count == 0)
                timer.Enabled   =   false;
        }
    }
}



file NetworkAdapter.cs

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace NetWork.Plus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a network adapter installed on the machine.
    /// Properties of this class can be used to obtain current network speed.
    /// </summary>
    public class NetworkAdapter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Instances of this class are supposed to be created only in an NetworkMonitor.
        /// </summary>
        internal NetworkAdapter(string name)
        {
            this.name   =   name;
        }

        private long dlSpeed, ulSpeed;              // Download\Upload speed in bytes per second.
        private long dlValue, ulValue;              // Download\Upload counter value in bytes.
        private long dlValueOld, ulValueOld;        // Download\Upload counter value one second earlier, in bytes.

        internal string name;                               // The name of the adapter.
        internal PerformanceCounter dlCounter, ulCounter;   // Performance counters to monitor download and upload speed.

        /// <summary>
        /// Preparations for monitoring.
        /// </summary>
        internal void init()
        {
            // Since dlValueOld and ulValueOld are used in method refresh() to calculate network speed, they must have be initialized.
            this.dlValueOld =   this.dlCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
            this.ulValueOld =   this.ulCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtain new sample from performance counters, and refresh the values saved in dlSpeed, ulSpeed, etc.
        /// This method is supposed to be called only in NetworkMonitor, one time every second.
        /// </summary>
        internal void refresh()
        {
            this.dlValue    =   this.dlCounter.NextSample().RawValue;
            this.ulValue    =   this.ulCounter.NextSample().RawValue;

            // Calculates download and upload speed.
            this.dlSpeed    =   this.dlValue - this.dlValueOld;
            this.ulSpeed    =   this.ulValue - this.ulValueOld;

            this.dlValueOld =   this.dlValue;
            this.ulValueOld =   this.ulValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Overrides method to return the name of the adapter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The name of the adapter.</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the network adapter.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Current download speed in bytes per second.
        /// </summary>
        public long DownloadSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dlSpeed;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Current upload speed in bytes per second.
        /// </summary>
        public long UploadSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ulSpeed;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Current download speed in kbytes per second.
        /// </summary>
        public double DownloadSpeedKbps
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dlSpeed/1024.0;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Current upload speed in kbytes per second.
        /// </summary>
        public double UploadSpeedKbps
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ulSpeed/1024.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you could use these files like this for example:

```
    private NetworkAdapter[] adapters;
    private NetworkMonitor monitor;
```

you trap the list of network devices, so you could check if your prefered network device is known or unknown

```
    monitor =   new NetworkMonitor();
    this.adapters   =   monitor.Adapters;
```

If you want you could measure the speed of download and/or upload if you want..

following the version of framework you have to included in the exe.config file this piece of code :(to avoid the error -> InvalidOperation : Instance 'XXX' does not exist in the specified Category)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <performanceCounters enabled="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```